# Programmatically retrieve SAML metadata of SF as a service provider

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

We have 3 full-sync sandboxes + our production org. Every month, the next planned sandbox is refreshed and re-configured.

Part of this process is that we enabled SSO on those sandboxes. Once the sandbox is back online, one of the steps is to provide our SSO team with the metadata file for each of the entity IDs we have configured. For example, we have 5 experience cloud sides, each enabled with SSO.

For this step, we go to each of those sites within the "SAML Single Sign-On Settings" page and download the metadata file to provide to the team. They then configure it with shibboleth to enable the connection etc.

This is a bit of a time consuming process for both sides, especially on a monthly occurrence.

Our SSO team has inquired if there is a way for them to point their shibboleth tool to a metadata file that it will poll for every 15 minutes, perform a delta on the configuration and update it if needed. Sounds great.

When I proceeded to inspect the download of the meta, it unfortunately requires you to be logged in. ie. https://mysite.lightning.force.com/idp/spdownload?sc=0LE5C00000000uo

Their tool that they use for the auto syncing can only perform a simple GET to a URL with no authentication.

After doing some research, I came across this public endpoint and provided it to the SSO team to see if it was what they needed:
https://mysite.my.salesforce.com/.well-known/samlidp.xml

They stated: "This is close, but this is for salesforce being the IDP.  This link is more similar to what we send you.  We need the Service Provider metadata url from salesforce."

After comparing the public facing file and the downloaded metadata, I can see there is a difference with its contents.

**The Question:**

Since I haven't been able to find a public facing URL for the files they need, I am trying to explore other options.

I was thinking about making a RESTful endpoint that they could hit which would return the contents of the `spdownload?sc=0LE5C00000000uo` metadata.xml for their tool to consume.

My concern here is that I don't know the risk of the `<ds:X509Certificate>` being in there as its different than the one shown in the `.well-known/samlidp.xml` from what I can tell.

The goal here is I need the contents of this "Download Metadata" file to be accessible to our internal SSO team so they can poll the contents and keep automate our SSO config after refreshes. As far as I know, the shibboleth tool can only perform simple GET requests to a non-authenticated xml file.

[image]

Any ideas how this could be implemented? Risks or other options?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont think there will be a public way to download this file via a simple GET url. I think your best bet would be to write a small program to login (most like via SOAP API) and download the file locally and have Shiboleth read it that way

Comment: `/idp/spdownload?sc=<id>` is the right answer. Nothing in there is unsafe, they're public keys.

Comment: I agree with @identigral the only issue is the "authentication" part

Comment: Thanks - I will look into how to get around the authentication piece if possible.